Opening the same image twice gives I/O operation on closed file error
The following is my code:
workbook = load_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.active
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)

def get_cell_image(image_loader, cell_name):
    image = image_loader.get(cell_name)
    image = np.array(image)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return image

get_cell_image(image_loader, 'A2')
get_cell_image(image_loader, 'A2')

The second time I'm trying to run the same line of code, I'm getting

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I'm trying to do two for loops. With the inner loop reading all the images in the Excel file. When the loop runs for the second time, I'm encountering this same error. I tried to simplify my problem by running the same image loader twice on the same cell. That resulted in the same error.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe you should create new image_loader before every image. Maybe it closes file after loading image and it has problem to load it again - and this may need to create new loader.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The Openpyxl code opens the image files on load but when an image file is read to get the bytes data it then closes the file. Therefore trying to read this data for the same image a second time fails as that image file is now closed.
The img._data() function does this so once its run once on an image you cannot run it again for the same image.
To do what you require you can save that image bytes data on first read, in this case into a dictionary against the cell co-ordinate.
Therefore on the first request for the image in cell 'A2' the cell is checked against global dictionary 'image_bytes_dict' and added with its data if it doesn't exist. The dictionary data is then used to process the image. On the second (and subsequent requests) since the cell does now exist in the dictionary, the bytes data does not need to be re-read and data will be taken from there directly.
This code sample doesn't use SheetImageLoader, it runs the same functions to obtain the data.
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import cv2
import io
from PIL import Image
import string


image_bytes_dict = {}  # Dictionary to hold image bytes data with cell co-ord as key 

def get_cell_image(ws, cell_name):
    for img in ws._images:
        row = img.anchor._from.row + 1
        col = string.ascii_uppercase[img.anchor._from.col]
        if f'{col}{row}' == cell_name:
            ### Add bytes data to dictionary with cell co-rods as key if not already exists
            if cell_name not in image_bytes_dict:
                image_bytes_dict[cell_name] = img._data()

            ### bytes data is always loaded from the dictionary 
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes_dict[cell_name]))

            image = np.array(image)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            return image


workbook = load_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.active


get_cell_image(sheet, 'A2')
get_cell_image(sheet, 'A2')


Thanks. I used similar approach then since I was short on time for further research. Thanks!
